# Skip Hardware Wizard (straight to "Have Disk..")

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bypassing “Found New Hardware Wizard” / Setting Windows to Install Drivers Automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/230838/bypassing-found-new-hardware-wizard-setting-windows-to-install-drivers-autom)

When I install hardware on a computer, I always have the driver file ready (either the disk or a download).  Windows insists that I use the "Hardware Wizard" anyways and takes a long time building the cache of PnP hardware available instead of letting me go straight to "Have Disk...".  Any way to avoid this behavior?