# Is there a way to reinstall the default drivers for Windows XP after replacing a new motherboard?

Tags: windows-xp

I changed my motherboard and CPU (I had an Asus P4p800-x).
When I tried to boot up my Windows XP and Windows 7 they both failed!.

After searching for many hours I found these crashes were due to the former motherboards drivers being present. I was following [how to repair Windows 7 install after replacing motherboard](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-repair-windows-7-install-after-replacing-motherboard/), but since my motherboard doesn't have any official drivers for Windows XP, I can't do the same thing for the Windows XP part.

I have access to the Windows XP installation partition. Can I do something about it from my current Windows 7? What can I do to boot up my Windows XP?

Comment: Your pretty much limited to installing it again.  Windows XP doesn't even have half the tools you require to solve this problem.  You would need to boot into the installation with the old hardware in order to remove the driver and place it in a mode, that would allow this to be possible.

Comment: Did you try booting into safe-mode to uninstall the old drivers?

Comment: @Synetech: Yes it doesnt work at all.

Comment: @Ramhound: This is not possible at all, my former MB is dead.

Comment: Define “failed” and “doesn’t work”. That could mean many things. What happens if you try to boot normally and in safe-mode? Does it hang during the [loading phase](http://www.sohologics.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/news0201/safe-mode04.jpg)? If so, what is the last driver it printed before hanging? Does it give one of many different possible errors? Does it show a black screen and just stop forever? Does it reboot by itself? Does the drive-activity LED flicker? You’ll need to be more specific because there are just so many things that could be preventing it from working.

Comment: And for the record, yes, it is indeed possible to get an existing XP installation running with a new motherboard (or even an *entirely new system*). It might be [(very) difficult](http://superuser.com/questions/230838/) depending on the circumstances, but it is usually doable without resorting to re-installing Windows.

Comment: I get the error 0x000007B , and this is the screenshot of my safemode booting and then failing.http://i41.tinypic.com/27xjyip.jpg
The full error is this :(0x0000007B (0xF789E924,0xC0000034,0x00000000,0x00000000)